# How to keep the connection pool from closing with a java driver on a mongodb?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, connection, connection-pooling

I'm in the middle of upgrading from java driver 2.12.3 to 3.3.0. Curiously it seems that the collection pool is suddenly "acting up".

My set up is as follows:

The Connection is established in the main thread:

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(0, 10)); // deprecated, replace soon
database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Example");
// java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

It's used in hundreds of threads:

```
org.bson.Document oldDoc = DBInteractions.readOneFromDb("articles");
```

using functions like this:

```
static synchronized Document readOneFromDb(String col) {
    return database.getCollection(col).find().limit(1).sort(new Document().append("count", 1)).first();
}
```

And for every DB interaction I get such a warning:

```
Sep 26, 2016 2:33:19 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMATION: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:42, serverValue:248}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

It looks as if the connection pool is closed after just one interaction. But why? *very puzzled* Anyone an idea?

Comment: No real answer, but a hint: you should have the MongoClient as the shared object which you only open up once and keep through lifetime. The MongoDatabase object is not thread-safe and should not be shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.1/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html

Look at the link. There are several method that can probably help you.
Look into the timeout related methods for **connection** and **connection pool**.

---

**EDIT**: added the correct answer (it was in the comments below)

```
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketKeepAlive(true).build(); 
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("host", options);
```

Comment: That 's what I did all afternoon, and the reason why I ask here. ;) Drawing a blank on more ideas.

Comment: see if this helps

'
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketKeepAlive(true).build();
}
and pass this options to 

MongoClient client = new MongoClient("host", options);'

Comment: great :) happy to help.

Comment: where do you add this?

Answer (score 4):

```
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketKeepAlive(true).build();
```

socketKeepAlive is now **Deprecated**.
It now **defaults** to **true** and disabling it is not recommended.