# Spring mongo driver connection pool close error

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have spring webflux/reactive server utilizing a singleton mongo database instance running on the same machine. Now, I have an rest endpoint in the server which triggers an external etl(python script using pymongo connection) on the db. But it then leads to pool close error on my spring server, and any subsequent database operations from the server fails.

```
2020-02-16T01:25:58.320+0530 [QUIET] [system.out] 2020-02-16 01:25:58.321  INFO 93553 --- [extShutdownHook] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:133}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

My etl runs for 10 secs, but mongo driver never reconnects after connection is closed from the pymongo side.

I tried mongodb configuration flags, but failed, don't know if there is a way. I am also willing to reconnect to mongodb on every rest call to avoid this, but any ideas/suggestions there.

I was hoping mongo_client should provide `onClose()` function, for the application to handle disconnections, but could not find any such handler.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703240/how-to-keep-the-connection-pool-from-closing-with-a-java-driver-on-a-mongodb)?

Comment: Tried did not work, @Valijon. `serverKeepAlive` option is deprecated, its `true` by default, still did not help.

Comment: @v78 I have the same issue right now. Could you solve this?