# why connection to mongodb is closed when I run my mini spring-boot project?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

*I am a beginner btw :)*

The error is the following :

> ```
> org.mongodb.driver.connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed
> ```

My main class is :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MangoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MangoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

My `CustomerRepository` interface :

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {
    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep the connection pool from closing with a java driver on a mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703240/how-to-keep-the-connection-pool-from-closing-with-a-java-driver-on-a-mongodb)

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar unfortunately, noo

Comment: You don't specify **where** or **when** you get the error, which is important. Please add the configuration you are using (your `application.properties`) and the dependencies you have defined in Maven or Gradle.

Comment: By default (without any configuration) you can connect to MongoDB on localhost and port 271017 - from your Spring Boot application. Is your MongoDB server up and running? If so on what host and port? Also, see [How to initialize MongoClient once in Spring Boot and use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-export-it-to-use-its-metho/61677205#61677205)

Comment: dosn't work for me :(